# How add last column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, razor, devexpress

I need add last column "action", and set in cell href `<a href="/?page=@Id">details</a>`
how do this in devexpress?

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "gvGrouping";

        settings.Columns.Add("Id");//not visible
        settings.Columns.Add("Service", "Сервис");

    settings.Columns.Add("Action", "Action");//I have error

    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

How I usually do it (don't know if it's THE best way, but it does the job):

```
 settings.Columns.Add(column =>
                                {
                                 column.FieldName = "Id";
                                 column.Caption = " ";
                                 column.Settings.AllowAutoFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
                                 column.Settings.AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False;
                                 column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
                                });
 settings.CustomColumnDisplayText = (sender, e) =>
                                          {
                                                if (e.Column.FieldName == "Id")
                                                {
                                                     e.DisplayText = // put your actionlink here                                                                                       
                                                }
                                          };
```

This gives you the ability to put whetever you like in there (an image, a URL, etc..). You can access the value of the Id by calling 'e.Value' or args.GetFieldValue("") for another property. Or you can just access the model (Model.blabId)..

Hope this helps

UPDATE:

I don't know how you've structured your grid, but this is how it should be (I think there is something wrong with the way you're calling the grid, that's why you're getting the error):

```
 Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
       //all your settings stuff in here
    }).Bind(Model.YourList).Render();
```

Comment: I get error `compilation Error

Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Can not convert lambda expression to type "DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridViewSettings", since it is not a delegate type`

Answer (score -1):

You could also use  SetDataItemTemplateContent

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
       var actionCol = settings.Columns.Add("Action");
       actionCol.SetDataItemTemplateContent(() =>
       { 
          Html.ActionLink("Action", "SomeAction", "SomeController", new { myParam =    Model.Param });
    } );
```

Comment: I get error compilation Error


Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Can not convert lambda expression to type "DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridViewSettings", since it is not a delegate type

Comment: I have edited the code. Column name must be changed. See if it helps